# Installing Node.js on Wine on Linux?

Tags: linux, wine, node.js

I know this may seem a little awkward, but how do you install Node.js on Wine on Linux, as opposed to installing directly onto Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but you can go to the nodejs website and download a copy for Windows and run that exe with wine.